# Connecting to COM ports fails

Tags: c#, serial-port, port

I fetched the list of available COM ports using

http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html

```
EnumPorts method reports
COM1 <Lokaler Port>
COM3 <Lokaler Port>
COM4 <Lokaler Port>
COM5 <Lokaler Port>
COM6 <Lokaler Port>
COM7 <Lokaler Port>
COM8 <Lokaler Port>
COM9 <Lokaler Port>
COM10 <Lokaler Port>
COM11 <Lokaler Port>
COM12 <Lokaler Port>
COM14 <Lokaler Port>
COM13 <Lokaler Port>
COM15 <Lokaler Port>
COM16 <Lokaler Port>
COM17 <Lokaler Port>
COM18 <Lokaler Port>
COM19 <Lokaler Port>
COM255 <Lokaler Port>
COM100 <Lokaler Port>
```

and wrote a script to try to connect to all ports (I have an FTDI device that I need to read/write from/to):

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace COM_detect
{
    class Program
    {
        SerialPort _serialPort;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program prog = new Program();
            prog.TryCOMPorts();
        }

        public void TryCOMPorts()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 19; ++i)
            {
                if (openPort("COM" + i.ToString()))
                {
                    closePort();
                }
            }
        }

        public bool openPort(string port_name)
        {
            try
            {                              
                SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort();
                _serialPort.PortName = port_name;
                _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
                _serialPort.Parity = 0;
                _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
                _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

                _serialPort.Open();
            }
            catch (SystemException ex)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("Error opening port: " + port_name + " Ex: " + ex.ToString());
                return false; 
            }

            return true;
        }

        public bool closePort()
        {
            try
            {
                _serialPort.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (SystemException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't seem to connect (even though a device is connected):

```
Error opening port: COM1 Ex: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'COM1'.
File name: 'COM1'
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Handshake handshake, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Boolean discardNull, Byte parityReplace)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
   at COM_detect.Program.openPort(String port_name) in E:\COM-detect\Program.cs:line 46
```

There are no COMX ports listed in the device manager either:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bttRR.png)

Comment: You may have the wrong driver installed.  First look at Device Manager to make sure the device is installed and not YELLOW.  Then try  Putty to make sure it works manually.  Finally go back to your c# code and try again.  Also the Baud Rate may be wrong.

Comment: What is "FTDI device"? Why you decide you can communicate with it using `SerialPort`?

Comment: @jdweng That was it; I had to uninstall the WinUSB drivers (I've been doing some tests with libusb). Now devices appear in the serial port dropdown.

Comment: The standard Microsoft USB driver is the default driver and does not work with a lot of USB devices.

Comment: @Sinatr Well, hello there! lmgtfy: https://www.ftdichip.com/USB.html something that can read/write through a USB connection. Because I was communicating with it about 3 1/4 hours ago using `SerialPort`.